# How do I create a download file link in React?

Tags: reactjs, download

I have a question, I'm working on a project of my own, and I've set up some buttons in React, but when I click on my download button I get back nothing but my website. How do I fix this?

Here's the code for my button:

```
<Button className="resume__Button2" to="" download="./files/Chris_Warren.pdf" component={Link}>My Resume</Button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually serving a path `<website>/files/Chris_Warren.pdf`? If you browse directly to that URL, is the pdf there?

Comment: I don't see any valid 'download' attribute on <button> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button. Can you please add more samples from your application?

Comment: @AlexHansen yes when you go to that location the PDF is actually there.

Comment: @PramodMali I'll look at that, maybe I simply overlooked something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are using React Router, you have to use this:

```
<Link to="/files/Chris_Warren.pdf" target="_blank" download>Download</Link>
```

or Button. both of them is possible but you have to note that "/files/Chris_Warren.pdf"  **is inside your public folder**.

Comment: I did move my files folder into my public one instead of in my src folder

Comment: `<Button className="resume__Button2" to="/files/Chris_Warren.pdf" target="_blank" component={Link}>My Resume</Button>` This is what I updated my code to @shahedmahmoudi, thank you for putting me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

There's another way if you don't want the user to see the path of the file by  adding a hidden button like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick={()=> document.getElementById("hiddenButton").click() >
Download 
  <Link hidden to={path_to_your_file} target='_blank' download id="hiddenButton"></Link>
</button>
```